# MySQL move where clause inside subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following MySQL query.  However, I need to move the `FIND_IN_SET` where clause inside the sub query which joins the `actions` table.

Is this possible?  When I try and move that part inside the subquery it gives me the error, `paths` column does not exist.

```
select 
    users_roles.role_id,
    ar.actions, 
    a.paths 
    from users_roles 
    join 
        (
            select 
                action_id,
                role_id,
                group_concat(action_id SEPARATOR ',') as actions 
            from actions_roles 
        ) as ar on ar.role_id = users_roles.role_id
    join 
        (
            select 
                id,
                group_concat(path SEPARATOR ',') as paths 
            from actions 
        ) as a on a.id = ar.action_id
    where 
        users_roles.user_id = 1 and FIND_IN_SET('/admin', paths);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, try this:

```
select 
    users_roles.role_id,
    ar.actions, 
    a.paths 
    from users_roles 
    join 
        (
            select 
                action_id,
                role_id,
                group_concat(action_id SEPARATOR ',') as actions 
            from actions_roles
        ) as ar on ar.role_id = users_roles.role_id
    join 
        (
            select 
                id,
                group_concat(path SEPARATOR ',') as paths 
            from actions
            having FIND_IN_SET('/admin', group_concat(path SEPARATOR ',')) > 0
        ) as a on a.id = ar.action_id
    where 
        users_roles.user_id = 1
```

Since the `paths` column you are passing to the function is actually the result of `group_concat()` function inside your sub-query, all you need to do is add a `HAVING` clause in the sub-query and change the alias of the column with the actual call of the function, which you also use to generate the data.

**Why `HAVING` and not `WHERE`?**

Because you're verifying the result of `group_concat()` which is an aggregate function. And the result of aggregate functions can be filtered only through a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @V4n1ll4 You're welcome. My mistake, since `group_concat` is an aggregate function. And when trying to filter an aggregate result you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: @V4n1ll4 Can you please remove the comments from this answer, since they are no longer required?